How to correctly use dynamic parameters in destination for redirects in Next.js?
I'm trying to set up a redirect in Next.js (using next.config.mjs) to dynamically redirect users from:

/profile to /profile/:playerId/details and
/profile/:profileId to  /profile/:playerId/details

The 2 option works fine, however, I'm getting the following error for option 1:
`destination` has segments not in `source` or `has` (playerId) for route {"source":"/profile","destination":"/profile/:playerId/details","permanent":false}

This is the relevant part of my next.config.mjs:
// next.config.mjs
export default {
  redirects: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/profile',
        destination: '/profile/:playerId/details',
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};


well, you cant redirect /profile to /profile/:playerId/details because the source has no playerId param, which the destination needs, which is why option 2 works fine. what's wrong with option 2?

Nothing is wrong with option 2, that works fine. But I want to redirect from /profile to /profile/:playerId/details

ok. so generally speaking, when you have a url param playerId in your case, you use that ID to look something up and get info for that thing. I'm guessing you have some concept of a player. so you use the player ID to look up the player, and then get the details for that player. so if you dont have the player ID, you wont be able to do that. but also logically it makes no sense. you'd need to either put a placeholder player ID so the destination would be profile/1/details and that might work, but then you're hard-coding a specific player id which is probably not what you want.
